# YUI Compressor throwing javascript error, using .net port

Tags: javascript, yui, yui-compressor

I have the following chunk of javascript:

(It's essentially the jquery.caret library)

```
﻿(function($,len,createRange,duplicate){
    $.fn.caret=function(options,opt2){
        var start,end,t=this[0],browser=$.browser.msie;
        if(typeof options==="object" && typeof options.start==="number" && typeof options.end==="number") {
            start=options.start;
            end=options.end;
        } else if(typeof options==="number" && typeof opt2==="number"){
            start=options;
            end=opt2;
        } else if(typeof options==="string"){
            if((start=t.value.indexOf(options))>-1) end=start+options[len];
            else start=null;
        } else if(Object.prototype.toString.call(options)==="[object RegExp]"){
            var re=options.exec(t.value);
            if(re != null) {
                start=re.index;
                end=start+re[0][len];
            }
        }
        if(typeof start!="undefined"){
            if(browser){
                var selRange = this[0].createTextRange();
                selRange.collapse(true);
                selRange.moveStart('character', start);
                selRange.moveEnd('character', end-start);
                selRange.select();
            } else {
                this[0].selectionStart=start;
                this[0].selectionEnd=end;
            }
            this[0].focus();
            return this
        } else {
            // Modification as suggested by Андрей Юткин
           if(browser){
                var selection=document.selection;
                if (this[0].tagName.toLowerCase() != "textarea") {
                    var val = this.val(),
                    range = selection[createRange]()[duplicate]();
                    range.moveEnd("character", val[len]);
                    var s = (range.text == "" ? val[len]:val.lastIndexOf(range.text));
                    range = selection[createRange]()[duplicate]();
                    range.moveStart("character", -val[len]);
                    var e = range.text[len];
                } else {
                    var range = selection[createRange](),
                    stored_range = range[duplicate]();
                    stored_range.moveToElementText(this[0]);
                    stored_range.setEndPoint('EndToEnd', range);
                    var s = stored_range.text[len] - range.text[len],
                    e = s + range.text[len]
                }
            // End of Modification
            } else {
                var s=t.selectionStart,
                    e=t.selectionEnd;
            }
            var te=t.value.substring(s,e);
            return {start:s,end:e,text:te,replace:function(st){
                return t.value.substring(0,s)+st+t.value.substring(e,t.value[len])
            }}
        }
    }
}(jQuery,"length","createRange","duplicate");
```

However, if I run that through YUI compressor, it doesn't work. It throws an error on line 1

I used http://compressorrater.thruhere.net/ to test this....

Using www.jslint.com I can see it's saying there is an unsafe character line 1, character 0.

I'm not sure how to solve this....
Ideally, I'd still like to use YUI Compressor, as there is a good .net port for it

Answer (score 0):

This was because there is a character in the file in question (jquery.caret)

I blogged about it here:

http://www.alexjamesbrown.com/blog/development/syntax-error-using-yahoo-yui-compressor-net-port-works-using-java-version/